# Adding permanent extensions to Chrome Automation Screen

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-extension, browser-automation

I wrote a python script to automate a login process using selenium. My login credentials are stored in LastPass (chrome extension), however, when I run my script, Chrome opens in an automation window without LastPass extention. I tried adding extension to the automation window but it gets destroyed each time I re-run the script. Is there any way I can install the LastPass extension to my automation screen permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a matter of retrieving stored credentials to automate your login, you could use the [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage).  Also it's persistent so you can close the browser and it will retain the creds you stored Object[key:Pair], and very easy to use.  Not to mention you wouldn't need to incorporate another extension.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that.

Comment: That should work, if so, please Check as the answer in case others may find useful.